# Jexcel and choice of type of variables

Tags: java, jexcelapi

The code is:

```
package reader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import jxl.Cell;
import jxl.Sheet;
import jxl.Workbook;
import jxl.read.biff.BiffException;

public class ReadExcel {


public static void main(String[] args) {
    Workbook workbook = null;
    try {
        /* Récupération du classeur Excel (en lecture) */
        workbook = Workbook.getWorkbook(new File("D:\\Data2.xls"));
        /* Un fichier excel est composé de plusieurs  feuilles, on y accède de la manière suivante*/
        Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheet(3);

       Cell a2=sheet.getCell(6,4);
        String contenuA1= a2.getContents();
       double  contenu=  Double.parseDouble(contenuA1);// The problem is here but why?
       System.out.print (contenu+" xx "); 

    } 
    catch (BiffException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
    finally {
        if(workbook!=null){
            /* On ferme le worbook pour libérer la mémoire */
            workbook.close(); 
        }
    }
}
```

}

The problem is that I can't  excute the program when I use parseDouble to convert a string in Double. When I remove the instruction with parseDouble, i dont have this problem but when I use it  I have comme error :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "1 256 491"
at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.parseDouble(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Unknown Source)
at reader.ReadExcel.main(ReadExcel.java:25)
```

Comment: Try using valueOf as :- 

    double  contenu=  Double.valueOf(contenuA1);
           System.out.print (contenu+" xx ");

Comment: Try to remove the spaces in the input string `1 256 491` should be `1256491`

Comment: I have always the same error :'(

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to remove the whitespace from you input string. Try this:

```
 Cell a2=sheet.getCell(6,4);
 String contenuA1= a2.getContents();
 contenuA1 = contenuA1.replaceAll("\\s", ""); // Removes whitespace
 double  contenu=  Double.parseDouble(contenuA1);// The problem is here but why?
 System.out.print (contenu+" xx ");
```

Comment: I do what you told me but I still have the same problem :'(

Comment: Do you get a different error message when you try, or the same error message?

Comment: I get the same error, I print my string and I find as result : 1 256 491 with whitespaces so the fuction recplaceall didn't remove it. I dont know why ;(

Comment: Try hard-coding a `String` of numbers into the `parseDouble` function to confirm that this is indeed the problem.